# If statement just works correctly once

Tags: java, android

I have a simple app which generates a random String and display it as a TextView. It replaces the letters with their transliterations. If the user types the correct transliteration, it prints "That's correct" otherwise it prints "Not exactly, it's: " + the correct transliteration. However, it works correctly just for the first time. After that, even when the user types the correct transliteration it says: "Not exactly, it's:".
By printing the answer, I checked if it detects the user input correctly; It does but it still doesn't work. I'm not sure which part of my code makes trouble.
I'd appreciate any help.

Here is a simple form of my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Random;

//Letter activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String wordStr;
    TextView resultTextView;
    EditText answerText;
    String result;
    TextView randomText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        randomText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomText);

        findViewById(R.id.newBtn).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.check).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        generateRandomStr();
    }

    //generates random word

    public void generateRandomStr(){

        String Chars = "Бд";
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (word.length() < 3) {
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * Chars.length());
            word.append(Chars.charAt(index));
        }

        wordStr = word.toString();
        randomText.setText(wordStr);
    }


    private  View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (view.getId()) {
                //Check button
                case R.id.check:

                    String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
                    String transliteration = wordStr.replace("Б", "b").replace("д", "d");
                    if (answer.equals(transliteration)) {
                        result = "That's correct";
                    } else {
                        result = "Not exactly, it's actually:" + " " + transliteration;
                    }
                    resultTextView.setText(result + " ");

                    break;
                //New button
                case R.id.newBtn:

                    resultTextView.setText(" ");
                    answerText.setText(" ");
                    generateRandomStr();
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.682"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.528" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.314"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.528" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/randomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.136" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.371" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.726" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try print out `transliteration`?

Comment: Yes, I printed the `transliteration`, even when it's the exact same as input it still says: "Not exactly, it's:"

Comment: Then the two strings aren't equal. Just "printing" looks identical doesnt make them identical. Some characters arent printed for example. You could, for example print out each string char by char in case of a "no match". Rest assured: "if" works as it should, and "equals" does as it should. If your code prints that second message, then your strings are NOT identical. For whatever reason.

Comment: Are you sure `setText(" ")` is what you want? Why not just `setText("")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an extra space in front when next button is `clicked`. Either remove the space by using `trim()` method.

```
String answer = answerText.getText().toString().trim();
```

or use `setText("")` instead of `setText(" ")`.